# TypeError when using gdal.Warp in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp

I try to use the gdal python binding to project a raster in *World Mollweide*.

```
import gdal 

map_raster_proj = pm.getTmpDir() + Path(map_raster).stem + '_proj.tif'
input_ = gdal.Open(map_raster)
gdal.Warp(input_, map_raster_proj, dstSRS='ESRI:54009')
```

but i get the following error :

> TypeError: in method 'wrapper_GDALWarpDestDS', argument 4 of type 'GDALWarpAppOptions *'

If I use gdalwarp from a terminal it runs without bug. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input and output arguments are reversed, the [function signature](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#Warp) is:

```
gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS, srcDSOrSrcDSTab, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I only take the stem of the Path object so I'm only manipulating strings but effectively I wasn't respecting the function signature. So much time for nothing....

Comment: @PierrickRambaud Ahh, missed the `.stem` bit.